# LOGGER.INFO and LOGGER.DEBUG are not populating in host (JAVA)

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm having this logger statements inside the class in java:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DemoClass.class);

LOGGER.info("info class");
LOGGER.error("error class");
LOGGER.debug("debug class");
```

I also tried using `LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "info LEVEL class");` But still it did not work.

I can only see `LOGGER.error msg` in my host where `LOGGER.info` and `LOGGER.debug` are not generating.

Also these logs are for my website where we are using and the args we are passing are:

```
argv =
        "-Denv.BRAZIL_CONFIG=--app=MYAPP -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/env/MYAPP/var/etc/jaas.conf -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/common/endorsed -classpath :/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/temp -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start";
```

EDIT:

This configuration is for Process Manager is set up to restart Tomcat

```
 childClass = PMSignaledChild; # How process manager communicates with process
    shutdownTimeout = 30;
    ignoreRestart = false;
    path = /env/MYAPP/jdk/bin/java;
    argv =
        "-Denv.BRAZIL_CONFIG=--app=MYAPP -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/env/MYAPP/var/etc/jaas.conf -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/common/endorsed -classpath :/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/env/MYAPP/var/tomcat/temp -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start";
    pwd= $ROOT;
    copies = 1;
    startupPriority = 1;
```

This is my application configuration where we did log4j2 migration.

```
JAVA_HOME = "$ROOT/jdk";
   PRE_CLASSPATH = "$ROOT/lib/mail-1.4.jar:$ROOT/jdk/lib/tools.jar";
   JVM_ARGS="-Duser.dir=$ROOT/var/output \
             
        -DappName=MYAPP \
        -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager \
        -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector \
        -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$ROOT$/log-configuration/log4j2";
   DOMAIN="testing";
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Why is this tagged log4j when you seem to be using java.util.logging? Also, you should post your logging config.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your current log level.
You can increase it per namespace using the following parameter:

```
-Dlogging.level.TLD.YOUR.NAMESPACE=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thank you for response .Tried this but still not getting info and debug log statements.

Comment: can you post your class namespace and the parameter you added?